# Android Studio App Unfortunately has stopped-Java code

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio, 2d

My app in Android Studio is OK but when I run it, it tells me `your app has closed`. The application is a card game.

**My code:**

```
        ## Heading ##
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {


            *Button btn_retry;*

            *int lastImageView = 0;
            int beforLastImageView = 0;
            int lastCard=0;
            int beforLastCard=0;
            int imageNumber=0;
            int beforImageNumber=0;

            int numberOfCards = 6;
            int numberOfImages = 30;*
            final ImageView[] Imageview = new ImageView[numberOfCards];
            int[] Imageview_Id = {R.id.img1, R.id.img2, R.id.img3, 

R.id.img4, R.id.img5, R.id.img6};

            final int[] images = {R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3, R.drawable.i4, R.drawable.i5,
                    R.drawable.i6, R.drawable.i7, R.drawable.i8, R.drawable.i9, R.drawable.i10,
                    R.drawable.i11, R.drawable.i12, R.drawable.i13, R.drawable.i14, R.drawable.i15,
                    R.drawable.i16, R.drawable.i17, R.drawable.i18, R.drawable.i19, R.drawable.i20,
                    R.drawable.i21, R.drawable.i22, R.drawable.i23, R.drawable.i24, R.drawable.i25,
                    R.drawable.i26, R.drawable.i27, R.drawable.i28, R.drawable.i29, R.drawable.i30,
                    R.drawable.i31, R.drawable.i32, R.drawable.i33, R.drawable.i34, R.drawable.i35,
                    R.drawable.i36, R.drawable.i37, R.drawable.i38, R.drawable.i39, R.drawable.i40};

            final List<Integer> cardlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();



            @Override
            **protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                clickOnButton1();**




                final List<Integer> imagelist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++) {

                    imagelist.add(i);
                }
                Collections.shuffle(imagelist);

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++) {

                    Imageview[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(Imageview_Id[i]);

                }


                final List<Integer> cardlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int i = 0; i< numberOfCards / 2; i++) {
                    cardlist.add(imagelist.get(i));
                }
                for (int i=numberOfCards/2;i<numberOfCards;i++){
                    cardlist.add(imagelist.get(i-numberOfCards/2));
                }


                Collections.shuffle(cardlist);

                for (int i=0 ; i<numberOfCards;i++){
                    Imageview[i].setOnClickListener(onClickImage);

                }


            };


            protected View.OnClickListener onClickImage= new

View.OnClickListener() {
                **@Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {**

                    switch (v.getId()){
                        case(R.id.img1):
                            imageNumber = 1;
                        case(R.id.img2):
                            imageNumber = 2;
                        case(R.id.img3):
                            imageNumber = 3;
                        case(R.id.img4):
                            imageNumber = 4;
                        case(R.id.img5):
                            imageNumber = 5;
                        case(R.id.img6):
                            imageNumber = 6;

                    }

                    android.os.Handler handler =new android.os.Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            String imageName="i"+cardlist.get(imageNumber);
                            int res = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", "com.example.arash.card");
                            Imageview[imageNumber].setImageResource(res);
                            lastImageView=(v.getId());
                            lastCard=cardlist.get(imageNumber);
                        }
                    },1000);

                    if (lastImageView != beforLastImageView) {
                        if (lastCard == beforLastCard) {

                            Imageview[imageNumber].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Imageview[imageNumber].setEnabled(false);
                            Imageview[beforImageNumber].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Imageview[beforImageNumber].setEnabled(false);
                            beforLastCard = 0;
                            beforLastImageView = 0;
                            lastCard = 0;
                            lastImageView = 0;
                        } else {
                            beforLastImageView = lastImageView;
                            beforLastCard = lastCard;
                        }
                    }

                    beforImageNumber=imageNumber;
             }

                };








            **public void clickOnButton1() {**

                final Context context = this;

                btn_retry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

                btn_retry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    ***@Override***
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        finish();

                        *startActivity(intent);*
                    }

                });

            }
```

Comment: Add the stackTrace that you get in terminal when your app crashes.